# Updating a BillObject via Bill.com's API in PHP

Tags: php, json, api

I'm having some problems with updating a Bill Object using Bill.com's API. I'm using their JSON API Client as Documented at http://developer.bill.com/api-documentation/code-samples/php/ , and tidied/available at https://github.com/altmind/bill-dot-com-php-api .

Reading in Objects is no problem; what I'm currently doing is reading in a Bill via JSON, and attempting to alter some fields within it, before sending back an update command. Below is a sample of the command I'm sending back, and expecting to be updated on Bill.com's side;

```
$api->update('Bill', json_encode($bill)
```

With the $bill array (obfuscated some values to protect customer data) containing;

```
array (size=20)
  'entity' => string 'Bill' (length=4)
  'id' => string 'billid' (length=20)
  'isActive' => string '1' (length=1)
  'vendorId' => string 'vendorid' (length=20)
  'invoiceNumber' => string 'invoicenumber' (length=11)
  'approvalStatus' => string '1' (length=1)
  'invoiceDate' => string '2016-01-10' (length=10)
  'dueDate' => string '2016-02-05' (length=10)
  'glPostingDate' => null
  'amount' => int 100
  'scheduledAmount' => int 0
  'paidAmount' => null
  'paymentStatus' => string '1' (length=1)
  'description' => null
  'poNumber' => null
  'createdTime' => string '2016-02-07T01:41:56.000+0000' (length=28)
  'updatedTime' => string '2016-02-07T01:41:56.000+0000' (length=28)
  'payFromBankAccountId' => string 'bankaccountid' (length=20)
  'payFromChartOfAccountId' => string 'chartofaccountid' (length=20)
  'billLineItems' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=19)
          'entity' => string 'BillLineItem' (length=12)
          'id' => string 'billlineitemid' (length=20)
          'billId' => string 'billid' (length=20)
          'amount' => int 85
          'chartOfAccountId' => string 'chartofaccountid' (length=20)
          'departmentId' => string '00000000000000000000' (length=20)
          'locationId' => string '00000000000000000000' (length=20)
          'jobId' => string '00000000000000000000' (length=20)
          'customerId' => string '00000000000000000000' (length=20)
          'jobBillable' => boolean false
          'description' => null
          'createdTime' => string '2016-02-07T01:41:56.000+0000' (length=28)
          'updatedTime' => string '2016-02-07T01:41:56.000+0000' (length=28)
          'lineType' => string '1' (length=1)
          'itemId' => string '00000000000000000000' (length=20)
          'quantity' => int 1
          'unitPrice' => int 85
          'employeeId' => string '00000000000000000000' (length=20)
          'actgClassId' => string '00000000000000000000' (length=20)
```

However, in attempting to send this through to Bill.com's API, I'm being returned with;

```
  protected 'message' => string 'Error during crud operation: 'Update', on obj type: 'Bill', data:
array (
  'obj' => '{"entity":"Bill","id":"billid","isActive":"1","vendorId":"vendorid","invoiceNumber":"invoicenumber","approvalStatus":"1","invoiceDate":"2016-01-10","dueDate":"2016-02-05","glPostingDate":null,"amount":100,"scheduledAmount":0,"paidAmount":null,"paymentStatus":"1","description":null,"poNumber":null,"createdTime":"2016-02-07T01:41:56.000+0000","updatedTime":"2016-02-07T01:41:56.000+0000","payFromBankAcc'... (length=2500)
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out - posting below for anyone who runs into the same issue.

BillCom's API documentation, unfortunately differs from their ready-made PHP API. Through trial and error, I've found the correct format for sending updated Bill details.

Firstly, the PHP API will automatically parse your PHP array to JSON. This would normally be fine - but the formatting will be incorrect. So, instead of relying on that, we'll need to construct our own JSON array. This will be in a slightly different format from the JSON array that's sent back from BillCom's 'Read' method.

The old way (as is also used in the current PHP API), will send;

```
  'obj' => '{"entity":"Bill","id":"billid","isActive":"1","vendorId":"vendorid","invoiceNumber":"invoicenumber","approvalStatus":"1","invoiceDate":"2016-01-10","dueDate":"2016-02-05","glPostingDate":null,"amount":100,"scheduledAmount":0,"paidAmount":null,"paymentStatus":"1","description":null,"poNumber":null,"createdTime":"2016-02-07T01:41:56.000+0000","updatedTime":"2016-02-07T01:41:56.000+0000","payFromBankAcc'... (length=2500)
```

So, firstly, forget about the 'obj' tag. this should read;

```
  'data' => {...
```

Then, the JSON array should actually be contained within a parent object, named 'obj'. There are also limitations on the data which can be sent back within the Bill JSON, which can be viewed at http://developer.bill.com/api-documentation/api/bill/ . Trying to send back all the data that you got from the 'Read' method will return with an error.

So, in summary, the actual data we should be sending should be in the following format;

```
'data' => {"obj":{"entity":"Bill","id":"id","isActive":"1","vendorId":"vendorid","invoiceNumber":"invoicenumber","invoiceDate":"2016-01-10","dueDate":"2016-02-05","billLineItems":[{"entity":"BillLineItem","amount":100,"chartOfAccountId":"chartofaccountid","lineType":"1"}]}}
```

Comment: please let me know how we use the same from postmen. I have tried passing the JSON but it always says parser error . I am passing the data in the body with x-www-form-urlencoded